# What does this notation in Maschke's Theorem mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, artinian

The statement of the theorem is as follows: If $F$ is the field of complex numbers and $G$ is a finite group, then $F(G)$ [...]"

I'm wondering specifically about what $F(G)$ is? Would I say "$F$ over $G$" or something else if I said it out loud? In the proof of the theorem, they say that $F(G)$ is a finite-dimensional algebra, so is $F(G)$ the notation for an algebra? In the course we've never defined what an algebra is.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, $F(G)$ is the [group ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) aka *group algebra*. I would say simply "$F$ $G$", and think it is unlikely to cause confusion among friends.

Comment: An answer I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2020532) explains how, historicaly, $F(G)$ "naturally" arose in the group landscape...